# I use the UIView `animateWithDuration:animations:` method to animate my view, it's bottom constant change, but it shows did not animate

Tags: ios, uiviewanimation

I use the UIView `animateWithDuration:animations:` method to animate my view, it's bottom constant change, but it shows did not animate.

My code is below:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *bottom_tableView;

...
// my animate method
- (void)hideSelf {
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{

        _upspringBackView.alpha = 0.f;
        _bottom_tableView.constant = -_tableView.bounds.size.height - 49;
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

        if (finished) {

            self.hidden = YES;
        }
    }];
}
```

I don't know why, my code is no problem.

Comment: Try to add **[self layoutIfNeeded]** to the animation block.

Comment: Like @Sergey said: When you animate views that use autolayout constraints, you need to call `layoutIfNeeded` (perhaps `setNeedsLayout` will work too, I think).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to animate the view by its NSLayoutConstraint, you should set the `layoutIfNeeded` method in the animations block:

Try this:

```
    _bottom_tableView.constant = -_tableView.bounds.size.height - 49;

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{

        _upspringBackView.alpha = 0.f;
        [self layoutIfNeeded];
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

        if (finished) {

            self.hidden = YES;
        }
    }];
```